# make doesn't run .py file

Tags: python, numpy, makefile, f2py

I am trying to create a Python module from Fortran code using `f2py`.  I have set up a Makefile for my project.  I am using MinGW and Python 3.2.2 on Windows 7.  When I run

```
f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f
```

everything compiles and runs fine.  However, when I create a target in my Makefile and run it, it does this:

```
> make compilef
f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, env python.exe C:\Python32\Scripts\f2py.py -c
 --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [compilef] Error 2
```

Why won't `make` run the command, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** Running the command shown in the output doesn't work:

```
> env python.exe C:\Python32\Scripts\f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However, the following does work:

```
> python.exe C:\Python32\Scripts\f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f
```

**EDIT 2:** This raises another question - What is `env` and why does `make` add it?

**EDIT 3:** Based on Florian's comment, it seems that the `env` was added by `make` due to the presence of the shebang line in f2py.py.  I edited f2py.py, adding an additional `#` in front of the shebang.  I now have the following problem:

```
>make compilef
f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\Python32\Scripts\f2py.py, f2py.py -c --compiler=
mingw32 -m itf itimes-f.f, ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
make: *** [compilef] Error 193
```

Comment: And when you try to run the command given in the error message?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, which command are you referring to?

Comment: The one that starts with `env`.

Comment: f2py.py probably starts with a line like this: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. That's where the `env` comes from. `env` simply calls the `python` interpreter (see [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/env/))

Comment: no, `env` is probably added by `make`, as make assums that it's running in a posix-conforming environment, where certain standard unix commands like `rm`, `mv`, `cp`, `env`, ... are available.

Comment: @mata, my version of `make` comes from MinGW.  Since MinGW is only intended for use on Windows, why would it assume that it is running in a posix-conforming environment?

Comment: @Florian, The first line is indeed `#!/usr/bin/env python.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's just a [convention](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Utilities-in-Makefiles) to write makefiles so they run in a standard unix environment.
Nevertheless, make comes from *nix and if you have make installed then you probably have msys which provides the basic tools, and scripts are executed in a unix-way, not like windows would do it...

An example makefile that works for me using mingw-make on windows:

```
all:
    ./test.py
```

With `test.py` having a shebang of `#!C:\\Python27\\python.exe`

or if python is in the PATH `#!python` is enough, as is:

```
all:
    python test.py
```